mysql find entries that are not posted within 3 hours



id
coordinatorId
time




5114
1
2024-05-30 11:13:30


5113
1
2024-05-30 10:13:22


5112
1
2024-05-30 09:13:14


5111
1
2024-05-30 08:13:02


5110
1
2024-05-30 07:12:52


5109
1
2024-05-30 06:12:38


5108
1
2024-05-30 05:12:33


5107
1
2024-05-30 04:12:29


5106
1
2024-05-30 03:12:17


5105
1
2024-05-30 02:12:09


5105
2
2024-05-30 02:12:09



Tried
SELECT DISTINCT coordinatorId 
FROM coordinator 
WHERE (coordinator.time < now() - INTERVAL 180 minute) NOT IN (coordinator.time > now() - INTERVAL 180 minute);

My devices report in every hour. How do I find the coordinatorId that has not reported in , in the last 3 hours, the problem is that it locates anything that was less then 3 hours which is included in coordinatorId = 1, it should only find coordinatorId 2.
With a number of variations. Nothing works.
Any Help?
Thanks,
Donald

IN and NOT IN need to be followed by a list of values, not a single expression.

(coordinator.time < now() - INTERVAL 180 minute) is either TRUE or FALSE. Why are you checking whether that's NOT IN something?

Does this answer your question? WHERE datetime older than some time (eg. 15 minutes)

Check the latest time that each coordinator has checked in against the limit.
SELECT coordinatorId
FROM coordinator
GROUP BY coordinatorId
HAVING MAX(time) < NOW() - INTERVAL 3 HOUR;

